# Noun for an individual that formulates a question and also for an individual that addresses an answer

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Given a person who formulates a question, may he or she be called the *questioner* or *enquirer*?  Likewise, may a person that addresses or responds an answer be called *answerer* or *responder*?

Which are the correct words?

Comment: These are fine, though **in**quirer is probably more usual. You may also use *quaerent* and *respondent*, but you have to be careful with *respondent* which also refers to one who 'responds' to a complaint in a court of law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to keep it all easy:

- **He who asks** something is the ***asker***.
- **He who answers** something is the ***answerer***.

Neither French nor Latin is needed here.